# Estimate the volume of the solid

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The question I have to answer is:

*Estimate the volume of the solid that lies above the square $R=[0,2]×[0,2]$ and below the elliptic paraboloid $z=15.4−x^2−1.6y^2$.* 
Divide $R$ into four equal squares and choose the sample point to be the upper right corner of each square $R_{ij}$. *Hint:* For your own benefit, you should consider sketching the solid and the approximating rectangular boxes.

---

**My (wrong) approach:**

(a) Have $4$ points $(0,0), (1,0), (0,1), (1,1)$ and plug them into $z$. I have :
    $15.4, 14.4, 13.8, 12.8$

(b) Have other $4$ points $(1,1), (1,2) , (2,1) , (2,2)$ , and repeat (a) and I have:  $12.8, 9.8, 8, 5$

I add all the $8$ points together times change of Area (i.e. $1*1 =1$) and I have:

$ ((15.4+14.4+13.8+12.8)+(12.8+9.8+8+5))/2 = 46 \text{ units}$

I don't understand what the error is. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

The upper right corners are $(1,1),(1,2),(2,1),(2,2)$  Following the instructions you should just add the values there to get $12.8+9.8+8+5=35.6$ if I use your values for the function.